# How to make a post request in Next 13 with app directory and RTK Query

Tags: redux, next.js, rtk-query, next.js13

**How can I make a POST request to my backend using RTK Query in NextJS 13 from the new api folder?**

What is the correct way to trigger a request?
I have tried the following 2 ways to dispatch and none of them worked:

```
//first try
const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
dispatch(addMemoria.initiate({firstName, lastName, birthDate: selectedBirthDate, deathDate: selectedDeathDate}));
//second try
addMemoria.initiate({firstName, lastName, birthDate: selectedBirthDate, deathDate: selectedDeathDate});
```

The expected outcome would be to have a successful POST request and a new Memoria Entry in the database

The Error I get:

```
hydration-error-info.js?32aa:27 An unhandled error occurred processing a request for the endpoint "addMemoria".
In the case of an unhandled error, no tags will be "provided" or "invalidated". Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available
    at headers (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/headers.js:17:15)
    at getServerSession (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:94:35)
    at prepareHeaders (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./src/store/strapiApi.ts:23:90)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:239:42)
    at step (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:44:23)
    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(:3000/e-memoria/app-client)/./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/rtk-query.esm.js:25:53)
```

The following post request is valid using my http client:

```
POST http://localhost:1337/api/memorias
Content-Type: application/json
authorization: Bearer ****************************

{
  "data": {
    "firstName": "FirstNAmeTest",
    "lastName": "LAstNameTest",
    "birthDate": "2021-09-01",
    "deathDate": "2021-09-02"
  }
}
```

RTK store config:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    strapiApi: strapiApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware(getDefaultMiddleware) {
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(strapiApi.middleware);
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

My Api Endpoint (the authorized GET request works):

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL + '/api/', //"http://localhost:3000/api/",
  prepareHeaders: async (headers, { getState }) => {
    const session : any = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
    if (session) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${session?.jwt}`)
    }
    headers.set('cache', 'no-store');
    headers.set('Cache-control', 'no-store, max-age=0');

    return headers
  },
})

export const strapiApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "strapiApi",
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["Memoria", "bla"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllMemorias: builder.query<{ results: Array<{ name: string }> }, void>({
      query: () => `memorias`,
      providesTags: ['bla'],

    }),
    addMemoria: builder.mutation<Memoria, Partial<Memoria>>({
      query: (body: Partial<Memoria>) => ({
        url: `memorias`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: createStrapiPOSTBody(body),
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'Memoria', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
});

export const { getAllMemorias, addMemoria } = strapiApi.endpoints;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can only call `getServerSession` in React Server Components. You do not have access to headers inside client components that are being rendered on the server. It seems like you are calling it from a client component right now.

Generally, you should also not use something like a `export const` for a Redux store in Next SSR, as that store will be shared by multiple users that way. Tbh., there isn't a good story on how to do all of that - it's still very much experimental.

Comment: Dear @phry, thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question. What I get from your answer is that Server-Side redux should not be used for any private data => no authorized API calls should be done with RTK Q on the server. How do you recommend to proceed then. Should I do redux only client-side and add "use client" in all my store files? That would mean that the whole platform is client-side. And I would only use server-side for the blog for instance, where people have to do just read operations. Best, Sergiu

Comment: Even files with "use query" will be executed on the server and have this problem of sharing global variables between requests, in an additional SSR run after RSC. 
For "traditional" Next SSR, `redux-next-wrapper` solves this. For Next's `app` directory, there is just nothing yet. Keep in mind that you are working with completely experimental tech here. Be sure to do a lot of experimentation and not run any of this in production before there is guidance from the next team saying it's safe.

Comment: Or in other words: it's nice to experiment. But if you want to build any real application, don't use the `app` directory. It's marked experimental for a reason.

Comment: I ran into this same problem today, so even with NextJS 14.1.0 it appears to be a problem. I have a client-side component that makes calls to server elements that try to add an Authorization header using `axios` interceptor. Same error message.